# Is the product of two even functions even or odd?

Tags: functions

Two even functions, say f(x) and g(x), when multiplied together give a function, say h(x). Now will h(x) be always even or odd? Or it can be either of these(case-specific)?

Comment: h(x) will be even

Comment: What did you attempt? Show what have you tried, we will help you get on track. This is not homework answering site.

Comment: @OP Please do not completely change the question, especially *after* it was answered. Rolled back.

Comment: $$h(-x) = f(-x)g(-x) = \big(-f(x)\big) \big(-g(x)\big) = f(x) g(x) = h(x). $$ $$ \text{So } h(-x) = h(x). $$

Answer (score 10):

Product of two even functions is even.

Proof: $h(-x)=f(-x)g(-x)=f(x)g(x)=h(x)$.

Comment: This ought to end by saying $\cdots=h(x). \qquad$